# Как мне брать фотографии из папки, где установлена программа?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть проект написан в Qt C++. Мне нужно запихнуть все файлы программы в инсталлер, но у меня есть одна проблема. Моя программа создает папку, а в ней еще папки, а уже там скриншоты(сохранения работы в программе), ну и прочие файлы.

Сначала я хотел, чтобы она делалась на диске "С", но там ничего не хочет создаваться. Видимо из-за того, что нужны права администратора. Но и с ними папки не создаются.

Ну вот я хочу чтобы они создавались в пути установления программы. При этом есть еще кнопка, которая открывает главную папку, где все лежит.

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать

```
QDir dir;
dir.mkpath("C:/Program Files/Labs/Результаты/");
dir.mkdir(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
```

Вот таким кодом я сейчас пользуюсь. Нужно чтобы вместо `C:/Program Files/` был путь установки. Причем он может быть любой на любом ПК.

Comment: Посмотрите `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в main()

```
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

И потом просто используйте так:

```
QDir dir;
dir.mkpath("./Labs/Результаты/");
dir.mkdir(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
```

ну или так еще вроде работает

```
dir.mkpath(":/Labs/Результаты/");
```

А вообще, уберите кириллицу из кода:)
Такие вещи, как кириллица в ресурсах хранятся обычно

Comment: да не только из кода - лучше и из путей убрать

Comment: `А вообще, уберите кириллицу из кода` лучше бы объяснили проблему. Голословное утверждение не то что не несет  пользы, является вредным, т.к. может противоречить стандартам проекта. Кириллица возможна, но требует дополнительной работы и соблюдения норм, ресурсы излишни и не менее проблематичны если нет планов создавать переводы\локализации.

Comment: ":/Labs/Результаты/" Обычно это файл из ресурсов, не из файловой системы. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html

Comment: @Swift мне интересно, где вы работаете, если у вас кириллица в коде "возможна"

Comment: @slavaguk Имелось в виду, что  стандарт на компиляторы позволяет  (и больщинство современных компиляторов). Это не рекомендуется по другим причинам, если используемые тулчейны или целевая платформа не поддерживают ту или иную кодировку, или архитектура не  предполагает строк кода вообще (тогда все метки кодировки переезжают в файлы, например, в xml). Компилятор в любом случае должен поддерживать как минимум unicode. Можно предположить что все до сих пор сидят в VS или в Builderах 10-летней давности. Такие места то же есть,  например одна БОЛЬШАя российская компания  до сих пор работает на VS6.

Comment: @Swift Дело даже не в кодировках и поддержке, а в принятых международных стандартах, которые основываются на опыте в поддержке кода, в корректной работе на разном железе и многом многом другом. В любой нормальной компании за кириллицу в коде бьют ногами.

Comment: @slavaguk "в принятых международных стандартах" как раз разрешение и указано (видимо кто-то невнимательно читал или читал американиский ANSI вариант) однако со вторым согласен. Кириллицу хранят в ресурсах для локализации. Разница в том что речь о строковых литералах а не о идентификаторах Если почитать последние стандарты, там еще дополнительная поддержка на это накручена. "Стандартных",  ресурсов не существует, релизация в Qt - одна из худших. А если считать внешний файл - "ресурсом", проблема та же, даже еще хуже, нужно самому забоится о формате файла (о исходнике заботится контроль версий)

Answer (score 1):

А как твоя программа будет работать у пользователя без прав администратора? Не нужно забывать о принципах информационной безопасности.
Хорошим тоном является отделение мух от котлет - данные отдельно, код отдельно. В винде этот принцип соблюсти до конца в принципе не возможно, но и тут есть правила хорошего тона - исполняемые файлы хранятся в %PrgramFiles%, настройки пользователя в %AppData%, файлы пользователя в профиле. В определении этих путей тебе поможет класс QStandardPaths.
Например можно поучить папку для записи скринов вот так

```
QString scr = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation) +
                                               QDir::separator() +
                                               "Скрины моей супер проги";
QDir path(scr);
if (!path.exists()){
    path.mkpath(scr);
}
qDebug() << path.absolutePath();
```

Comment: QStandardPaths ! Да! И настройки хранить через QSettings!